# Why is my specific page tpl.php not being used?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I can't seem to use a unique `page--xxxxxxx.tpl.php` for a specific page.

I created a "page" content, filled it in, and gave it a path alias. Let's say: "`mypage/mycontent`". Then I created a `page--mypage--mycontent.tpl.php` file in my theme's root. Instead of using it, my `page.tpl.php` is being used.

I was under the impression that Drupal 7 automatically searches for template suggestions using the format of `page--path.tpl.php`, is this incorrect? Do I need to include specific code in my template.php file first? I did try clearing the theme cache, btw and that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a node, try to rename your template file to **page--node--NID.tpl.php** and then flush the cache, also don't forget to replace **NID** with the nid of this node to be something like **page--node--11.tpl.php** :)

Hope this works... Muhammad

Comment: There is no need to rename (and it may not always be possible, not all paths points to nodes). The file name `page--mypage--mycontent.tpl.php` will work, provided all cached data is cleared out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

Your impression is correct, and `page--mypage--mycontent.tpl.php` (i.e. the one you've already tried) is the correct file name to use to override the `page.tpl.php` for a page with that specific path "`mypage/mycontent`".  You don't need to change anything else.

However, in addition to clearing Drupal's cache, you *also* need to clear the browser's cache.  In most browsers, including Firefox and MSIE, you do this by holding down the SHIFT key while reloading the page.  Without clearing the browser's cache, you will not be able to view your template suggestion in the browser.